# import class/package placed in another package of same/higher level of hierarchy

Tags: java, package

I have two folders pack1 and pack2 in my desktop.
pack1 contains file1.java file and the code is:

```
public class File1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){     
    }   
}
```

and pack2 contains file2.java and the code is:

```
import pack1.File1;
public class File2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){     
    }   
}
```

I successfully compiled file1.java and file1.class is created in pack1 but I got error while compiling file2.java:

```
error: package pack1 does not exist
import pack1.File1;
            ^
1 error
```

from the above error what I thought is I can only import class/package which are present in same or sub-directories because Pack1 is not in the same directory in which I am compiling(current working directory = $HOME/Desktop/pack2) please correct me if I am wrong.

If my understanding is correct how can I import file1 in file2.

Comment: You should describe your actual problem.  What error are you getting?  Please be specific.  To import subPack1 all you do is `import subPack1;`

Comment: Reading from your question there shouldn't be any problem importing any class in any package in same module. Plz provide examples.

Comment: Imports have nothing to do with the "current" package. The association with directories is misleading. Classes are resolved from the base folders listed in Java classpath.

Comment: actually I have a java file in subPack1 and I need to import subPack2.
suppose i need to import a package which is placed in current directory i will import it directly but here package subPack2 is placed inside pack2 which is having parent level of hierarchy.

Comment: If my answer isnt sufficient, then you really need to read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Show us *enough* code to repro the problem. You see, you *explaining* what your code does ... isnt really helpful. Because it means we have to rely that you really understand what you are doing here.

Comment: @GhostCat I have edited my question please do check.

Comment: You aren't telling us HOW you compile. Also note: IF that java source code is **complete**, then your classes are missing a PACKAGE statement like `package pack1;`. Seriously, this is super basic stuff. Instead of you trying to come up with your own thoughts, I suggest you get a good book or tutorial. There is sooo many existing material that guides you step by step what you need to do when you start using packages. See http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/packages.html for example.

Comment: @GhostCat I always use package statement but this is my doubt not the way I code, by the way I compiled normally(javac $FILE_NAME). If you need any other information please comment.

Comment: @GhostCat Please Ignore the rules and focus on question because above code is fine in compiler perspective.

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand:

- "the real" class name is always `the.complete.package.WhateverClass`
- there is **no** concept of "sub packages".

Sure, from a *directory* perspective the classes for `a.b` and `a.c` will all sit in folders within the `a` directory, but for anything inside `a.b`, it still has to use the full name `a.c.Whatever`

Thus your import always look the same, like:

```
import com.pack1.subpack2.TheClass
```

In other words: when your code sits in `a.b`, there is **no** difference in importing from `a.c` or `x.y.z`, you simply always give the full class name, with *all* the packages that belong to it.

Comment: what i was trying to ask is if there are two packages B and C in package A and if a file in package B needs to import file which is present in package C what import statement should i write as my current directory is B if I import A.C (A is not inside B) how does the code work it throws me an error saying package A.C does not exist.
If my question doesn't seems to be clear I'm extremely sorry.

Comment: Your question is clear, and my answer addresses it. I really dont know what else to say. Forget about "sub packages" and directories. You ALWAYS simply import using the full name, which includes ALL packages. There is no such thing as "the current" package and a "relative" view on other "sub packages. It is always import A.C. ...